# Centrally divided layout with animation (ONLY CSS)

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

**IMPORTANT NOTE: only CSS/HTML, but not javascript (client does not allow it**)

recently started the homepage of my site and wanted to make a centrally divided layout. Want to place the logo on the middle and one picture on top of it with a button to lead to the page, and one below it with the same function.

The animation should be a hover over the buttons (or defined area around it) as seen in the comp I did here:
[GIF ANIMATION OF WHAT IS INTENDED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj8Ez.gif)

Similar to what is intended: https://jsfiddle.net/vja85zgL/

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

#wrapper:hover #left:not(:hover) {
  width: 25%;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

#wrapper:hover #right:not(:hover) {
  width: 25%;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

#left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

#innerleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

#innerright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#right:hover {
  width: 75%;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

#left:hover {
  width: 75%;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="innerleft">
            TITLE 1
        </div>
    </div><div id="right">
        <div id="innerright">
            TITLE 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As seen, if hovering over the button, the background image behind the button shows itself "fully" (no rescaling), the logo (showed as B) moves down to 25% and the button not hovered scales down in size and font size and the image behind it slides under it where the user cannot see it properly (the user cannot see it by scrolling down).

If hovered on the other button the animation goes to the other button and image background.

There should be a delay of 2 seconds before the layout comes back to the starting position

DETAILS:

- **NO JAVASCRIPT ALLOWED, client doesn't allow usage**
- Should be responsive, so no hovering on touch devices
- The image must not resize or loose proportion
- Full screen layout
- Mouse simulates user.
- Animation should return to initial position after 3 seconds if mouse is not hovering
- Initial position is 50%-50% (almost, due to the logo which is 150x150px)
- End position should be 75%-25%.

Have been loosing my mind the last 2 days wondering how to do it as I am a beginner at `CSS` but didn't find a way yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Available code of what has been done already to the design (total mess...):

```css
#business-top {
   height:50%
    width:100%
}
#business-button {
  height:3em;
  width:12em;
  background-color:#2B2A2A;
  border: .2em solid #ff7600;
  border-radius:1.8em;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:3em;
}
#logo-separator {
 text-align:center;
}

.separator {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   padding: 0;
   height: 0;
   width: 100%;
   max-height: 0;
   font-size: 1px;
   line-height: 0;
   clear: both;
   border: none;
   border-top: 1px solid #ff7600;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ff7600;
}

#logo {
  margin:auto;
  max-width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden
  margin-top:-75px
  
}
#photography-bottom {
   height:50%
    width:100%
}

#photography-button {
  height:3em;
  width:12em;
  background-color:#2B2A2A;
  border: .2em solid #ff7600;
  border-radius:1.8em;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:3em;
}
h1 {
  color:#ff7600;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.4em;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:2.2em
 }
```

```html
<div id="business-top"
 <a href="www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com">
  <div id="business-button">
   <h1>BUSINESS</h1>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>

<div id="logo-separator">
<div class="separator"></div>
  <div id="logo"><img src="https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/Assets-for-website/i-CsMnM3R/0/Th/800x800-round-Th.png"</div>
  </div>

<div id="photography-bottom"
 <a href="www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com">
  <div id="photography-button">
   <h1>PHOTOGRAPHY</h1>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you increase area of buttons once hovered , then you may have some results in CSS only:

> *trick comes from pointer-events and pseudo to increase hoverable area*

```css
/* tricky part */

div {
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

div:hover {/* will be catch by child with pointer-events auto */
  flex: 3;
}

div:first-child {
  background: turquoise;
}

div a {
  pointer-events: auto;/*  if a is hovered, so is its parent */
  position: relative;/* this could be for the div parent if you want to cover its area */
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  border: 3px solid;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px;
  color: #222;
  background: #aaa;
}

div a:hover:before {/* increase size of button only once hovered */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -200px;/* coordonates used to increase pseudo size from its relative position parent. tune to your needs */
  bottom: -200px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* layout */
body,
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

hr:before {
  content: url(http://dummyimage.com/50x50);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#"> button style</a>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
  <a href="#"> button style</a>
</div>
```

From your update snippet :

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}

#business-top {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

#business-button {
  height: 3em;
  width: 12em;
  background-color: #2B2A2A;
  border: .2em solid #ff7600;
  border-radius: 1.8em;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo-separator {
  text-align: center;
}

.separator {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  font-size: 1px;
  line-height: 0;
  flex: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ff7600;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff7600;
}

#logo {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -75px;
  position: absolute;
}

#photography-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#photography-button {
  height: 3em;
  width: 12em;
  background-color: #2B2A2A;
  border: .2em solid #ff7600;
  border-radius: 1.8em;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  color: #ff7600;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2.2em
}

#business-top,
#photography-bottom {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  /* min-height: 200px; you ma want this to avoid logo and button to overlap */
}

#business-top a,
#photography-bottom a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

#business-top:hover,
#photography-bottom:hover {
  flex: 3;
}

#business-top a:hover:before,
#photography-bottom a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="business-top">
  <a href="www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com">
    <div id="business-button">
      <h1>BUSINESS</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="logo-separator">
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div id="logo"><img src="https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/Assets-for-website/i-CsMnM3R/0/Th/800x800-round-Th.png"> </div>
</div>

<div id="photography-bottom">
  <a href="www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com">
    <div id="photography-button">
      <h1>PHOTOGRAPHY</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbvgga

Comment: Thats exactly what I intended, but once I load it on to my page it does not run anything... See here: https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/

Comment: @luiggi19 ?? copy/paste into your doc just like that ? .. there's like more than 5000 css rules loaded  ... are you serious  ? :)

Comment: The site adds its own code as well in the platform... I have no control on the others :( Only lets add html/css as in "blocks", no heading or "full page" control

Comment: Thanks anyway! Will try a way around to use the code though :) Makes me want to change from client already... Thanks again :)

Comment: @luiggi19 i added a snippet update from the code you left here . some tags where not closed properly ,

Comment: Thanks so much @GCyrillus! :) Gonna play with it to see if i can run it. Thank you very much, reallly appreciate it!

Comment: Wow... Its so rare... If finally summed up everything and the design on desktop is ok, but in responsive it looks awfully. Also... the animation runs but not when its hovering, just when resizing window or other events... No clue on why is that so, but makes me not want to trust smugmug... See here... https://jsfiddle.net/lluisballbe/78cfdjho/ The site works well on 1920x1080 screen, here: www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com